# SQL Server function/stored proc to return a set of aggregations based on a set of points

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of x,y coordinates - let's say they represent map locations of cell phone pings. The table also has a personID to represent the owner of the phone.

I also have a function (which could be changed to something else to suit this solution) that accepts a set of points as a table variable and generates some aggregations of them (average and stdev in both directions). The example shows the table type and a function that could do this.

```
create type tblCoordinate AS table (x float, y float)
go

create function PointsAggregations(@pts tblCoordinate readonly)
returns table as
    return
        select avg(x) AvgX, avg(y) avgY, stdev(x) stdevx, stdev(y) stdevy
            from @pts
```

Question is how would I structure this so I could get a table of these aggregations by PersonID. That is, I would like to call this function and pass it the unique set of points for every PersonID in the table, and end up with a table of structure.

```
PersonID, avgX, avgY, stdevX, stdevY.
```

Feels like a weird reverse-cross apply kinda thing, but I can't quite figure out if it's possible. Note: the actual problem is much more complicated than the simple aggregations shown here - I am trying to encapsulate an algorithm that creates a "confidence ellipse" of the points - lots of math involved that aren't applicable to the posted question - so simply performing the aggregations within a single query and getting rid of the function isn't a solution.

Comment: Can you add `PersonID` to you `tblCoordinate` type? Then you could `GROUP BY PersonID` inside `PointsAggregations`.

Comment: How about sharing the table you are referring to, some sample data and the desired output? This explains the kinds of things you should post. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/